# A question on $n$-divisible groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $n^iG$ denote the subgroup $n^{i}G=\{n^{i}x;x\in G\}$.

Is  $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}n^{i}G$, $n$-divisible?

Comment: Zev Chonoles I need to it for my paper.

Comment: @TomHarris: right. if $G$ is $n$-torsion-free, then yes that intersection is divisible, but in general no it is not possible to choose a consistent system of $x_i$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Yeah I realised that about 2 minutes after I posted the answer, hence the delete. I wondered if one could do a little more work to show that the  $n$-torsion is not a problem, but then I had to go.